# Threading OR multiple flow of control in Pacman

Tags: c, multithreading, controls, pacman

I am planning to write a Pacman game in C language, right from scratch. The most basic challenge that I am facing is how to maintain multiple flows of control at the same time.
I mean how does the Pacman move, the ghosts move, the score being updated -- all at the same time. In general it is very common for all games. Is any kind of threading involved here?
If so can anyone please tell as to how to make your program do many things at the same time (it will be helpful if you tell for C language).

Thanks in advance

Comment: you might also ask on gamedev.stackexchange.

Answer (score 4):

One of the fundamental principle in real time game development is the **game tick**. It represents a small unit of time for things to happen in. So you might have a tick every 0.100 seconds. The smaller the tick, the finer control you have.

You can think of them as really fast turns with a time limit on them. If you don't do anything on that turn you forfeit the turn.

Comment: well, thanks a lot, but i am still wondering as to how to set the time -slice

Comment: @Matthew that's not how most GUI programs operate. The two are exact opposites in fact. An event loop does nothing if an event doesn't happen. A game loop, on the other hand, will be doing lots of work regardless of external inputs.

Comment: Thanks, removed for clarity. I didn't mean to imply that games development used a message loop, but rather that the mechanism to catch changes in state is almost always handled by an iterative process of some kind, and not the spawning of threads.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's pretty unlikely that the original version of Pac-Man was multithreaded in the sense we use the term today.  It was more likely implemented as a simple loop with some kind of interrupt support.  You can do the same to implement rudimentary multithreading - write your program in a `while (1)` or `for (;;)` loop, and set up a timer to interrupt your loop at regular intervals to perform the screen updates.

Comment: I won't downvote, but I disagree with the recommendation of interrupting the loop. The rendering loop and game loop should be completely independent of eachother.

Comment: @glowcoder - absolutely, if you have real threading support.  What happens if you don't, and your system only has a timer interrupt?  I expect Pac-Man was written without any kind of operating system support.  I was just trying to explain that sort of environment.  I didn't really intend my answer to be a recommendation, just a description of how the original game is likely to have been implemented and an idea of how to do something similar in C.

Comment: @carl : can you please tell me  how to interrupt a loop at regular intervals?  are you pointing to the function kbhit();

Comment: @glowcoder What do you mean by independent? Two other loops? Or one loop interleaved with implementation of both.

Comment: @Timothy, I'm not familiar with `kbhit()`.  You'll have to read your operating system documentation for information on how to do it on your machine.

Comment: The original Namco Pac-Man ASB released in 1980 was based on an 8-bit Zilog Z80 chip and definitely had nothing even resembling multi-threading.

Comment: @all: can anyone please show me a sample code, where more than one thing happen at the same time i.e 1) waiting for the user input 
2)updating the score at the same time

Comment: @carl: also can you please tell me as to how to interrupt a for loop, i mean using what command in C, if i am using a windows platform?

Comment: @timothy you may want to edit the question insead of asking for sample code here

Comment: +1 @Tim, though arguably any kind of interrupt handling capability "resembles" multithreading. =)

Comment: @pajton well i am not saying that i a need  the code, but i am saying can anyone tell me how to make two infinite loops run at the same time. this would be hard to visualise without a sample code.